# Move a chunk of text within a std::string to the left by X amount of chars

Tags: c++, c++11

What is an efficient way to shift the text within a std::string, starting at some offset, to the left by X amount of characters?

Example:

```
(Some sTring here)
```

Shifted to the left by 1, starting at T, would yield:

```
(Some Tring here)
```

**Background Info**

In a compiler for a text pattern language, in which text of the form:

```
(some expression here)
```

represent expressions to be replaced with some value. Those expressions can appear interspersed with text; something like the following:

```
There are ($count) types of things.
```

The above would be replaced with something like the following, after the text is evaluated by the compiler.

```
There are 42 types of things.
```

Now, I want support the ability to 'escape' expressions, so that text that would normally represent expressions can be written verbatim. So this:

```
There are \($count) types of things.
```

would be outputted like this:

```
There are ($count) types of things.
```

Basically, all that needs to happen is for the text after *There are* to be moved by 1 byte to the left. I was trying to think of an efficient way to do this. I wish I could memmove std::string's data buffer from '(...' by 1 byte to the left, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

I hate the idea of copying a big chunk of a string just to move the contents to the left by 1 character.

So, I'm hoping there is a better way than to do something like this:

```
auto size = buffer.size()
auto temp = buffer.substr(parentPosistion, size - parentPosistion)
buffer.assign(temp, parentPosistion - 1)
buffer.resize(size - 1)
```

Comment: Assuming you're writing this data to a secondary output stream as you go, is there a reason you can't simply skip over the backslash character then pass through the source text until you get back to whitespace?

Comment: I'm modifying the original std::string passed to the compiler.

Comment: @Dess Then [string::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) is what you want. See my answer.

Comment: @MoosBoys damn you! now you have me thinking whether just having another working buffer, and filling that as I go, is a better way to go about this. I'll ask a new question about that.

Comment: @Dess If you never need to insert new characters or refer back to old locations, you don't even need a second buffer - you can just keep a read pointer and a write pointer and update in place.

Comment: @MooseBoys Your comment triggered something in my mind. I've been going about this with a sledged hammer approach. I'm now excited about comming up with efficient ways to accomplish this kind of text evaluation. How fun! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use [string::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) to remove slash and then proceed with further operations. `erase` internally should be an efficient `memmove`, since `string`'s data is stored in continuous block of memory.

Example:

```
string s = "There are \\{$count} types of things.";
cout << s << endl;

size_t slash_pos = s.find("\\");

if(slash_pos != string::npos)
    s.erase(slash_pos, 1);

cout << s << endl;
```

Output:

```
There are \{$count} types of things.
There are {$count} types of things.
```

[Working sample](http://ideone.com/DGaLgm).

---

You did not specified the amount of input data, but yes - this approach can be slow for large strings, containing multiple slashes.

In such case, you would want to remove all slashes in single run. It is possible with [std::remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/):

```
string s = "\\{$count1} \\{$count2} \\{$count3}";
cout << s << endl;

s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '\\'), s.end());

cout << s << endl;
```

Output:

```
\{$count1} \{$count2} \{$count3}
{$count1} {$count2} {$count3}
```

Explanation: `std::remove(b, e, v)` transforms range [b; e) by removing all elements with value equal to `v` and returns iterator to end of new sequence. Then, we use this iterator to remove redundant characters. For example, if you simply called:

```
std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '\\');
```

Second output would be:

```
{$count1} {$count2} {$count3}t3}
```

Comment: This approach will be pretty slow for large files - you're going to end up moving many parts of the string multiple times, not to mention the fact that you'll scan the entire remaining string for every backslash, when it only really needs to be done once.

Comment: @MooseBoys Yes, you're right! Amount of data wasn't specified. I updated my answer with much more efficient solution for such case, based on `std::remove`. I think, that's probably one of the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `std::rotate`, will shift left at some `offset` by an arbitrary amount `X`, reducing the length of the string by `X`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void shift_left(std::string& str, std::size_t offset, std::size_t X)
{
    std::rotate(std::next(str.begin(), offset),
                std::next(str.begin(), offset + X),
                str.end() );
    str = str.substr(0, str.size() - X);
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Some sTring here";
    shift_left(str, 5, 2); // Outputs: Some ring here
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove e.g. all back slashes, then the shortest solution I can think of is this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "There are \\{$count} types of things.";

    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\\'),str.end());

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

And I doubt there is a more efficient solution. If you want to remove multiple different characters in one go, you can use remove_if.